# Проблемы с PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Пытаюсь настроить pythonpath для импорта собственных модулей.
В файле .bashrc добавил следующие строки

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/root/dev/pinger:/root/new_bots/bots_utils"
```

В supervisor conf.d:

```
[environment]
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/root/dev/pinger:/root/new_bots/bots_utils/
```

Но при запуске supervisor выдает ошибку `No module named 'bots_utils'`

Структура следующая:

```
bot_utils:
     -case1:
         -script.py
     -case2
```

Ошибку выдает при запросе `from bot_utils.case1.script import script`.

Что не так? Использую Ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В pythonpath нужно добавлять путь, где лежит модуль (или несколько модулей), а не путь самого модуля (т.е. нужно добавлять `/root/new_bots/`, а не `/root/new_bots/bots_utils/`)
2. Т.к. вы ничего не написали про содержимое модуля `script.py`, то будем считать, что в нем нет объекта с именем `script`. Если это так, то импортировать модуль нужно как
   `from bot_utils.case1 import script`

   Если нужно импортировать объект из модуля `script.py`, то нужно импортировать так: `from bot_utils.case1.script import func1`

#### Ниже рабочий пример

**Дерево директорий (`new_bots` находится в `~/stackoverflow`):**

[image: Дерево директорий]

**script.py:**

```
def func1():
    print("func1 executed")

print("script.py imported")
```

**Тестовый модуль, может находиться в любой директории:**

```
import sys
import os

# Добавляю в pythonpath так, чтобы не портить глобальное значение
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/stackoverflow/new_bots'))

from bot_utils.case1.script import func1

func1()
```

**Результат запуска:**

```
script.py imported
func1 executed
```